# matplotlib graph generation issue

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am generating both pie chart & bar graph parallelly.Sometimes the pie-chart is formed as a combination of both pie & bar graph. i.e,like piechart with bars..I can't post image here as I dont have permission.My code is :

```
x = ['01-04', '02-04', '04-04', '05-04']
y = [2, 3, 3, 1]

if plotType=="bargraphs":
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
    ax.bar(range(len(y)), y, width=0.3,align='center')
    plt.xticks(range(len(y)), x, size='small')
elif plotType=="charts":
    labels = x
    fracs =  y
    plt.pie(fracs, labels=labels,autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True)
plt.savefig('/home/user/graphimages/foo2.png')
```

Comment: you want pie chart and bar chart in separate figures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `plt.close()` to close current instance of matplotlib. If it stays open and this function/script is called again, next figure would be plotted in the same figure. So add `plt.close()` after `plt.savefig()`